# session[:previous_url] with endless scrolling

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When a user logs in or signs up in my application they are redirected back to the page they were on.

This is the code that does that in the application_controller.rb:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  session[:previous_url] || root_path
end
```

The problem is I'm using ajax and will_paginate to implement endless scrolling. When a user has scrolled past the first page and then they login they are redirected to a URL that looks like this:

```
www.example.com/path_=1412539956365&page=6
```

showing only the posts on page 6. How do I simply redirect back to:

```
www.example.com/path
```

Comment: Well, I guess you should store the previous url only for non ajax requests. So just check if the request is not `xhr?` only then set the previous url else the previous url is nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regex to strip out the query strings. Here is an example using the rails console:

```
 ?> session[:previous_url]
   => www.example.com/path_=1412539956365&page=6

 ?> session[:previous_url][/[^\?_]+/]
   => "www.example.com/path"
```

You can change your function to:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  session[:previous_url][/[^\?_]+/] || root_path
end
```